# NullPointerException in if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I've run into a NullPointerException in the following if statement;

```
public Player players[];

public void sortPlayers() {
    int n = players.length;

    for (int pass=1; pass < n; pass++){
        for (int i=0; i < n-pass; i++) {
            if(players[i].getLastName().compareTo(players[i + 1].getLastName()) > 0)
            temp = players[i];
        players[i] = players[i+1];
        players[i+1] =  temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I've googled the error report, but nothing seems to fit. If it helps, below is the Player class and the `getLastName()` method. Also, the expected data to be sent to the Player class would be a name, in the form of first-name then last-name, so something like "Bobby Joe."

```
public class Player {

public String[] name;

public Player(String inputname) {

    name = inputname.split(" ");

}

public String getLastName() {
    return name[1];
}
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**- Sorry, yes, this is Java.
**DOUBLE EDIT** -I've put the complete source code up onto a Pastebin if anyone would care to take a look at it. The error has been narrowed down to whenever the **players[i]** array is called in the **Team.sortPlayers()** method.

http://pastebin.com/sJKTpJA9

Comment: So am I to assume this is C#?

Comment: @EdS. Java, given capital `S` in `String`, lower-case method names, and OP's question history.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Where are you initializing the array of Players?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Well C# has `System.String`, which `string` is an alias for, but you're probably right considering the history.  My (round-about) point was that I/we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @icarusalways The array of Players is for players that are part of the Team class.

Comment: @JospehCusco: You should always post representative code.  Everything I can see says that you never initialize the array to begin with and it is null.

Comment: @EdS. The array has been initialized, for sure. However, I'm looking to see if it was ever filled.

Comment: @JospehCusco: Sounds to me like you have an array of `null`s.  You need to assign each element to a `new Person()`.

Comment: @EdS. I could have sworn I did give them data. In fact, I know I did. I put a System.out.println statement in the same group that adds data to the array.... however, when I ran the program again, this was the result... `--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
[LPlayer;@7f423820
[LPlayer;@7f423820
[LPlayer;@7f423820
[LPlayer;@7f423820
[LPlayer;@7f423820
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Team.sortPlayers(Team.java:31)
 at Project3.main(Project3.java:25)

Process completed.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the if statement:

```
for (int pass=1; pass < n; pass++){ 
    for (int i=0; i < n-pass; i++) { 
        if(players[i].getLastName().compareTo(players[i + 1].getLastName()) > 0) 
        temp = players[i]; 
    players[i] = players[i+1]; 
    players[i+1] =  temp;
    }
 }
```

If, in the first pass (i.e. i == 0, the compareTo method returns a value equal to or less than 0, the statement assigning temp a pointer to element 0 of the players array will not execute, temp will have a null pointer and the next two lines, not conditionally executed in the scope of the if statement, will assign element 1 to element 0 of the players array and a null pointer to element 1.

On the next pass (i.e. i == 1), this will then result in a java.lang.NullPointerException because now, the players[1] element has a null pointer from the first pass.

Depending on the order of names input, the exception might or might not be thrown if, on the first pass, the compareTo method returns a value > 0. From that point on, temp will have a valid pointer but whatever it points to will get swapped with the i+1th element even if it is not pointing to the ith element. The array's name contents will likely get mangled because the name sawp will not occur as desired.

Fixing the code segment to read:

```
for (int pass=1; pass < n; pass++) { 
    for (int i=0; i < n-pass; i++) { 
        if(players[i].getLastName().compareTo(players[i + 1].getLastName()) > 0) {
            temp = players[i]; 
            players[i] = players[i+1]; 
            players[i+1] =  temp;
        }
    }
}
```

will cure the problem and also have a better indentation practice.

One visible indicator of the problem is that the indentation in your sample, although not normal practice for if and for scopes, still indicates that only the first line of the array element swap is in the scope of the if statement instead of all three lines.

If scope mistakes are a common root of software errors.

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
if(players[i].getLastName().compareTo(players[i + 1].getLastName()) > 0)
```

has a lot of possibilities to throw NullPointerException:

- players[i] can be null (e.g. you are not properly initializing your array)
- First `getLastName` can return null (if your `name` member variable is null)
- players[i + 1] can be null

Answer (score 0):

Well... something here is obviously null.

```
if(players[i].getLastName().compareTo(players[i + 1].getLastName()) > 0)
```

It could be

```
players
players[i]
players[i].GetLastName()
players[i + 1]
players[i + 1].GetLastName()
```

We can't know which, you'll have to use a debugger.

Comment: Whenever the players array is called it comes up with the NullPointerException. I'm going to work backwards til I find where this happened, but I'm going to post the complete source code as an edit to the problem.

Comment: @JospehCusco: PLace a breakpoint on that line.  Is `players` null?  is `players[i]` null?  keep moving down that path and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shown.

`players` itself is null because you never initialize it (i.e. there is no `new Player[x]` in the code you have shown).  When you do

`int n = players.length;`

it go boom.  You want something like

`public Player [] players = new Player[n];`

somewhere after you know what `n` is.  Perhaps initialize it in the constructor

```
public Player [] players; // like you do now
...
players = new Player[n]; // in some constructor
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have `this.players[k] = new Player(names[k]);` in my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your .getLastName() returns null, and you get a null pointer exception when you try to call compareTo() on an object that is null.

Make sure the last name won't return null, or add a null check around it if null is valid

Comment: It could be that or four other possibilities.

Comment: There are other possibilities, but it at least illustrates the approach to debugging this.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite it; I already tried putting a hardcoded a dummy output on the .getLastName() method, and I still get the NullPointerException. This is very perplexing to me ._.

Comment: Ok, but use that same approach. Check anything in the code that you call a property or a method on. What does the error msg say? Anything about a line number?

Comment: The if statement was the line number, sir.  Working backwards to try and find the problem now ._.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a debugger to see which part of the statement is giving the `null` result.

Alternatively, you could break out the code a bit to make it easier to find the problem.

```
String playerName = players[i].getLastName();
String nextPlayerName = players[i+1].getLastName();
if(playerName.compareTo(nextPlayerName) > 0) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped with debugging. I've found out that it is a problem whenever players[1] is called.

Answer (score 0):

Better you try to print the names before using if condition check whether you are getting a null exception or not.

Comment: Oddly enough... I'm not getting null. I'm getting a memory address for each call, though not the data associated with it. ex: Player@5472fe25, Player@498b5a73, Player@5bdf59bd, etc. Idk, maybe its not a memory address, but it is very confusing ._.

Answer (score 0):

i think `players[i + 1].getLastName()` gives null pointer when pointer reaches to last index.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you initialise your players array correctly

```
    for(int i=0; i < numPlayers; i++){
        playerArray[i] = new Player("Joseph Blog");
    }
```

Make sure all players have the space or else when getlastname is called there will be a null value for last name. Perhaps you should change the constructor to take two strings instead, because then you could allow middle names also, and would not need to split the string each time you needed the last name.
Make sure you also do not access and index of the array that is out of bounds.